# How do I identify hashtable keys with multiple values in powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have a hashtable created from an array like this:

```
$employeesHashtable = $employees | Group-Object -Property Initials -AsHashTable
```

How do I find keys having multiple values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative to using [`.GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.getenumerator?view=net-6.0#system-collections-hashtable-getenumerator) can be using the hash table [**Keys**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.keys?view=net-6.0#system-collections-hashtable-keys), the key collection implements [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?view=net-6.0) and can be enumerated without issues:

```bash
$keysWithMultipleValues = $employeesHashtable.Keys.where{ $employeesHashtable[$_].Count -gt 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
$keysWithMultipleValues = $employeesHashtable.GetEnumerator() | `
  ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]@{ Key = $_.Key; Count = $_.Value.Count } } | `
  Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 }
```

Comment: FWIW you can skip the `ForEach-Object` invocation completely: `$employeesHashtable.GetEnumerator() |Where-Object { $_.Value.Count -gt 1 }` (will likely be slightly faster)

Comment: If you're using `.GetEnumerator()` you should reverse the order for efficiency, first filter: `$employeesHashtable.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Value.Count -gt 1 }` then construct your object